# Use javap to get method signatures in for Android Activity

Tags: android, javap

When I write in command line `javap -s java.awt.Label`, I succesfully get signatures for `Label`. Now I want to get signatures for Android Activity class. But if I write `javap -s android.app.activity` it results in `ERROR: Could not find android.app.activity`.

What am I doing wrong? Should I change something in PATH env var or whatever?

Comment: You should call it on the class--or is that a typo?

Comment: @Dave Newton Er... Activity is a class as far as I know. How do I change my cmdline request to get Activity method signatures?

Comment: Er.... `android.app.activity` isn't. `android.app.Activity` is. And the ADK classes have to be on your classpath; I can't tell from here if they are or not. (If javap even works on them; not sure when/how things are lunk and/or dexxed.) And `PATH` is not related to `CLASSPATH` (and in general I prefer `-cp` anyway, to avoid issues.)

Comment: @Dave Newton `javap -s android.app.Activity` did not help either.

Comment: @Dave Newton Thank you for your answers. Where is classpath set so that `javap` could find it?

Comment: Via `CLASSPATH` or `-cp`?

Comment: @Dave Newton Thanks! I ended up with `javap -s -classpath android.jar android.app.Activity`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Go to your apps directory and

```
javap -s -classpath bin/classes com.example.myActivity
```

**Edit**

for Android core classes add `bootclasspath`

```
javap -s -bootclasspath /opt/android-sdk/platforms/android-8/android.jar -classpath bin/classes android.app.Activity
```

Comment: Thanks :) Why not just add it to the classpath, though?

Comment: @Dave Newton: Actually I work from within Eclipse and have projects targeting different Android versions (different android-X/android.jar files), so I have no CLASSPATH set manually anywhere.

Comment: I'll be more explicit: why not just add it to the `-classpath` parameter?

Comment: @Dave Newton: no real reason :)

Comment: @Dave Newton: Interestingly it really makes a difference as `rt.jar` and `android.jar` are different: `javap -s -classpath /opt/android-sdk/platforms/android-8/android.jar:bin/classes java.lang.System` contains `getCallerClass()` and `javap -s -bootclasspath /opt/android-sdk/platforms/android-8/android.jar -classpath bin/classes java.lang.System` does not ...

Comment: ... but only for OpenJDK as it seems.